# Python regular expression is not matching all expected words

Tags: python, regex, findall

On regexr.com I have developed a regular expression that matches certain types of proper names. Here's the expression:

```
\b([a-z]?[A-Z]+[\w]*[ ]*)+\b
```

You can see it live with numerous examples being matched as expected at 
http://regexr.com/3bifh

E.g. from a string *Moby Dick or the White Whale by Herman Melville* it matches `Moby Dick`, `White Whale` and `Herman Melville`

I am trying to reproduce this in Python, with less success. Here's the code:

```
import re

text = "Moby Dick or the White Whale by Herman Melville"
print(re.findall(r"\b([a-z]?[A-Z]+[\w]*[ ]*)+\b", text))
```

The output is:

```
['Dick ', 'Whale ', 'Melville']
```

This matches only the last part of every result from above. 
Why is the expression not working in Python?

Comment: Everything that is highlighted on the regexpr.com fiddle page.

Comment: "Possibly a lowercase letter, then one or more uppercase letters, then optionally more letters, and optionally a space" -- doesn't this regex basically boil down to `\w+` or am I missing something?

Comment: You mean r"\w+"? No.  I am trying to match proper names/abbreviations, like 'United States', 'USA', 'Moby Dick', 'Edgar Allen Poe' or 'iPhone'. The key part is the uppercase letter.

Comment: I kinda get that but at the moment your regex is so broad it will match just about any alphabetical string with any number of spaces at the end, as long as it has an uppercase letter _somewhere_. It might be more efficient at this point to just check if `s != s.lower()` or similar.

Comment: The point is, I need to match the title case words tha follow each other. Like, 'Edgar Allen Poe' as one item and not 'Edgar', 'Allen' and 'Poe' as three items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex engine only remembers the last group when multiple groups are matches.

You can use this instead

```
 print (re.findall(r"\b((?:[a-z]?[A-Z]+[\w]*[ ]*)+)\b", text))
```

Comment: Good, but I don't want to split the matched parts.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster edited.No `split` required now.Your original regex is intact now :P

Answer (score 3):

Turn the capturing group to non-caturing group.

```
print(re.findall(r"\b(?:[a-z]?[A-Z]+[\w]*[ ]*)+\b", text))
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/3), it matches the first part but captures the second part. `re.findall` would give the first preference to captures then comes the matches. So it prints out the second part.

Alter your pattern like blow, if you don't wznt to match the trailing space character.

```
r'\b[a-z]?[A-Z]+\w*(?: [a-z]?[A-Z]+\w*)+'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/4)